# Is there such a thing as a FREE program which has the Photoshop feature of "lasso around a mold and press Delete to remove it" feature?

Tags: photography, image-editor, photoshop

Adobe Photoshop has this feature, introduced a few years ago, which I don't understand how I ever could live without:

1. You lasso-select an area, such as a birthmark or mold.
2. You press the Delete button.
3. It fills in the mold intelligently with surrounding data, making it "magically disappear".

Of course, this has always been possible by smudging in the surroundings into the mold/defect, or by "cloning" nearby parts over it. Both with Photoshop itself and other programs. However, this is *much* more involved and annoying, and in practice, it rarely looks as good as this tool makes it look. At least not for me, without significant effort.

Ever since I dropped Photoshop forever (subscription nonsense, spying/bloat/annoyances, etc.) and started using Krita, I've been missing this feature.

Is Krita planning to get this soon? Or is there any other (freeware) software that can do this one task? It's truly a killer feature, and it wouldn't surprise me if Adobe paid some really juicy salaries to extremely smart programmers to implement it...

Comment: With GIMP there's a plugin called "Resynthesizer" which does exactly what you describe: lasso an object, fire the plugin action, and gone it is. See eg. [this tutorial](https://www.scriptol.com/design/gimp/removing-objects.php). Resynthesizer is [available at Github](https://github.com/bootchk/resynthesizer), including install instructions. Not sure how well it works with current versions (description is for GIMP 2.6, and the plugin wasn't updated since 2018), hence just a comment; if it fits your bill, I can make it an answer. GIMP is available for Linux and Windows, so is the plugin.